# Pyspark vectorize a collectionRDD of dictionaries into a single dataframeRDD?

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

So I have a CollectionRDD consisting of OrderedDict elements.  I want to perform KMeans clustering anaylsis on them, but to do that, I need to get them all into a single dataframe first.  Is there way to do this in pyspark?

For example, if I have the following two dictionaries:

```
{"A":"1","B":"BEE","C":"123","Username":"john"}
{"B":"MN","C":"87","D":"Apple"}
```

I'd like to get a dataframeRDD that looks like:

```
A     B    C   D    Username
1     Bee  123      john
      MN   87  Apple
```

I know I can do this type of thing iteratively with a for loop in regular python, but I'm going to be dealing with a lot of data, so I'd like to use pyspark to perform this operation

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is flat, as in the example, the simplest thing you can do is to map to `Row` and call to `DF`.

```
from  pyspark.sql import Row

keys = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Username')
row = Row(*keys)

rdd = sc.parallelize([
    OrderedDict([('A', '1'), ('B', 'BEE'), ('C', '123'), ('Username', 'john')]),
    OrderedDict([('B', 'MN'), ('C', '87'), ('D', 'Apple')])
]) 

df = rdd.map(lambda xs: row(*(xs.get(k) for k in keys))).toDF()
df.show()

## +----+---+---+-----+--------+
## |   A|  B|  C|    D|Username|
## +----+---+---+-----+--------+
## |   1|BEE|123| null|    john|
## |null| MN| 87|Apple|    null|
## +----+---+---+-----+--------+
```

**Warning**:

It is also possible to convert to DF directly without intermediate `RDD[Row]` but this method has been deprecated and is not particularly robust.

Comment: Thanks!  Works great.